# Curved thick arrows on canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

i tried to draw a curved thick(more than 1px) arrow on a canvas element. But i don't know how. I have drawn a straight arrow with stroke on the canvas element and when i added the fill option it doesn't really locked like an arrow, seamed like it had the wrong perspective. Maybe someone has a idea how to draw a thick, maybe about 5px thick curved arrow on an canvas element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can draw a curved arrow using 2 canvas context drawings:

- A Bezier curve for the shaft
- A triangle of lines for the arrowhead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/x2dy6/

[image]

**The shaft is just context's cubic Bezier curve:**

```
ctx.moveTo(bez.sx,bez.sy);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(bez.cx1,bez.cy1,bez.cx2,bez.cy2,bez.ex,bez.ey);
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.stroke();
```

**The arrowhead is just a triangle made of context line-to commands:**

```
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(0,-10);
ctx.lineTo(15,0);
ctx.lineTo(0,10);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
```

**The arrowhead is positioned at the end of the shaft using context's transforms (translate+rotate):**

```
ctx.translate(bez.ex,bez.ey);
ctx.rotate(endingAngle);
```

**You need the angle at the end of the curve to rotate your arrowhead at the proper angle.**

That proper ending angle can be calculated like this:

```
var pointNearEnd=getCubicBezierXYatT(
    {x:bez.sx,y:bez.sy},
    {x:bez.cx1,y:bez.cy1},
    {x:bez.cx2,y:bez.cy2},
    {x:bez.ex,y:bez.ey},0.99);
var dx=bez.ex-pointNearEnd.x;
var dy=bez.ey-pointNearEnd.y;
var endingAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

// helper functions

function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

**Here is a complete code example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var bez1={sx:50,sy:150,cx1:125,cy1:75,cx2:100,cy2:225,ex:200,ey:130};

    drawCurvedArrow(bez1);

    function drawCurvedArrow(bez){

        // calculate the ending angle of the curve

        var pointNearEnd=getCubicBezierXYatT(
            {x:bez.sx,y:bez.sy},
            {x:bez.cx1,y:bez.cy1},
            {x:bez.cx2,y:bez.cy2},
            {x:bez.ex,y:bez.ey},0.99);
        var dx=bez.ex-pointNearEnd.x;
        var dy=bez.ey-pointNearEnd.y;
        var endingAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

        // draw the arrow shaft

        ctx.moveTo(bez.sx,bez.sy);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(bez.cx1,bez.cy1,bez.cx2,bez.cy2,bez.ex,bez.ey);
        ctx.lineWidth=5;
        ctx.stroke();

        // draw the arrow head

        var size=ctx.lineWidth;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(bez.ex,bez.ey);
        ctx.rotate(endingAngle);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(0,-size*2);
        ctx.lineTo(size*3,0);
        ctx.lineTo(0,size*2);
        ctx.lineTo(0,0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

    }

    // helper functions

    function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
        var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
        var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
        return({x:x,y:y});
    }

    // cubic helper formula at T distance
    function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
        var t2 = T * T;
        var t3 = t2 * T;
        return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
        + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
        + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
        + d * t3;
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fantastic job! It is possible to create the same arrow outside the canvas? Inside a div or whatever...?

Comment: @Ninita Sure. You can use CSS `position:absolute` to place a canvas over a Div element and draw arrows "inside" the Div. You can make the canvas cover the whole page and draw arrows anywhere on the page! Problem: Canvas is always a B-T-W (big transparent window). Solution: The key to overlaying Canvas is to make it "get out of the way" (not listen for events) which you can do be setting it's `pointer-events:none;`.  You could also consider SVG where you can draw the arrows but not have to worry about the B-T-W. SVG drawing commands are very similar to Canvas drawing commands--just more terse.

Comment: I put the canvas in the background. Over the canvas I position divs absolutely. And in the canvas I render Bézier paths for the relations between the divs. This makes an Entity–relationship model. I tried if first with SVG, but [I was not able to get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73646351/402322).